# Layered navigation column count higher than products shown (duplicate brand)

Tags: configurable-product, layered-navigation

Hi we have layered navigation and want to filter on manufacturer. There are 40 products. 36 shirts and 4 t-shirts. This 40 is shown correctly in the main area.

but! the filter in left column shows

- brand A (36)
- brand C (8)
- brand B (4)

Question: Brand A and B are correct ... but what is brand C doing there.

Also when clicking brand C I see 8 products that belong to brand A. And I have checked on product level under websites + Brand/manufacturer field that is correctly set to brand A

Reindexed all. And cleared cache.

Can this be a duplicate entry in database? (where is the layered column getting the count from - in relation to the main product area)

Many thanks, Sean

Comment: First, rebuild the indexes and flat tables.  And in case you have a comfigurable products that have brand A and some of the subproducts have brand C then it should behave this way.

Comment: Rebuild indexes done. Also includes flat tables no?

Comment: Where could I locate the duplicate coming from? Search in flat tables for the duplicate?

Comment: The products for the C brand, are they configurable?

Comment: Yes they are.  ....

Comment: So..the configurable products have brand A, but some of the simple products associated to the configurable products have brand C. That's why you see them as brand C also. This is my bet. Tell me if I'm right.

Comment: yep, you are right! Super thanks to you. I will post the answer and accept .. and maybe add screenie as proof

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

**The situation**: some simple products residing under the configurable product have (somehow) taken on the incorrect brand.So the configurable product has brand B, but a simple product beloning to the configurable product has brand C.

**The solution**: either remove all the brand attributes on simple product level (on our site brand is set only for configurable products at global level). Or if brand is obligatory on simple product level then update it to brand B (in this example).

With special thanks to @Marius

[image]